# Convert .Net LINQ Query to Angular 2 TypeScript / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, angular, typescript

I've got the following C# LINQ query which I need to port to Angular 2.

```
var groups = funds.OrderBy(g => g.DefaultGroupName).GroupBy(g => g.DefaultGroupName)
                        .Select(grp => new { GroupName = grp.Key, Funds = grp.ToList().OrderBy(f => f.ZOrder) });
```

This is what I have at the moment (which doesn't work). As you can see, I'm very new to Angular so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
// get the list of funds, grouped by Default Group Name
getFundGroups(): Observable<FundGroup[]> {
    const url = this.baseUrl;
    const funds =  this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => <Fund[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);

    const groups = funds.groupBy(fund => fund.DefaultGroupName)
                    .flatMap(group => group.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []));
    return groups;
}
```

Comment: This is more than just TypeScript/JavaScript. It looks like you might be using Angular 2 or React or something else to get the `Observable<T>` type. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan looks like rxjs to me.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it doesn't work".  In what way doesn't it work?  What was the output?  How is that different from the output you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can get use of LINQ for Angular

https://github.com/Angular-Public/ng2-linq

```
import * as Enumerable from 'linq';
```

then in your function you can write things like this.

```
let groups = Enumerbable.from(funds).where(x => x.Active);
```